# ASP.net ajax background process

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have simple web application (asp.net - ajax) I have a web form which has several RadioButtonLists , visitors can choose Items and then I have to calculate some things and show it.

I use updatepanel, and AutoPost back for RadioButtonList, when one Item selected , I do a calculation based on selected Item.and put the result in a Label.

I want to do this calculation on a background process and if user select another option( another RadioButton list ) while app doesn't finish current calculation, when I update Label text, the last user selection will be clear.

how can I manage this like a javascript , and without any intrude users can check all options and I calculate in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http is a stateless protocol so if you send two requests, they are isolated to each other. When you requests, you get response from server for that request. You need to handle this on client side, so if another *request* is sent before the previous request completed, than don't show the previous request *response*.